# Best strategy for XLS content sync from the cloud into an iOS or Android app memory

Tags: c#, javascript, mobile, cloud, storage

I am developping a mobile app using Unity3D framework which is a C#/Javscript 3D engine, working on desktop and mobile plateform.

I need to recover the content of an XLS file on a cloud-based storage (Dropbox or GoogleDrive), then process it on the mobile plateform to transform it into a local SQLite database.
The mobile app will regulary check for modification on the remote xls file, and push it locally if needed to process it.

The framework I use (Unity3D) allow me to work with both C# and Javascript technologies.

What would be the best strategy to implement such a fonctionnality.
I'm totally newbie with web API, and I've seen in Dropbox documentation that there is several possibilities to interact with a cloud folder.

Is there a possiblity to fetch the content of an xls document into the mobile device memory (with writing to its local drive)? What would be the easiest/more elegant way to achieve it?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Unity3D supports using managed DLLs in your project. So you can look at using one of the following libraries:

http://sergeytihon.wordpress.com/2013/09/29/dropbox-for-net-developers/

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-cs

and choose one.

There's also code for reading excel files from Unity3D on the wiki: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Load_Data_from_Excel_2003

And code for using SQLite: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SQLite.

From there putting it together is up to you, the documentation from each link should be more than enough to implement what you want. I'd recommend abstracting the differences in platforms here (Google Drive vs Dropbox) from your main game (It doesn't sound like you've made up your mind on one), in case you want to change them later on. In my experience, operations between the two are similar enough to make changing over reasonably straight forward down the road as long as you're using the proper abstraction techniques.

Comment: Thanx for your answer Assorted Trailmix,
I finally used this:
[link](http://u3d.as/content/echo17/boxit/3e7)
It allows me to get a xls sheet throw an https URL. Then i transform it into DataTable.